# How can I get a random document from a MongoDb collection, and then display each of the fields of that randomly selected document in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor

I am pulling a random document from a MongoDB Collection. Then I'm trying to display all the fields of that random document in HTML.

I am able to get a random document just fine, but when I try to display the fields of that document, they are all jumbled. Here's what I mean:

```
Template.hutch.helpers(
{
    //function returns one random book from a collection of books
    'book': function()
    {
        return BookList.find(randomBook);
    }
}
```

This returns 1 random book from my collection. (I know the (randomBook) isn't correct, i'm just getting the point across. The function is a bit larger but it returns one random element from my book list)

I want to display the contents of THIS book in HTML.

When I do {{book.Title}}, {{book.Publisher}}, {{book.Etc}}, the values don't align because it's getting a random book every time. (as you would expect, the function gets a random book. So it gets a random title, random publisher, etc). I would like to get all the information from the same book.

I also know that in the helper function you can call: `return BookList.find()`

And then in HTML the call `{{book 1}}` would return `[Object object]`.

I have tried `{{book 1.Title}}`, `{{book[1].Title}}`, `{{book(1).Title}}`, etc. But none of that works.

> I guess what I'm asking is: How can I get a random book from a list of books, and then display each of the fields of that same book to HTML.

My project is an attempt to populate a table with a random book's information when you click a button. All the books are stored in a database, and I want to select a random book, display the Title, Publisher, etc in an HTML table.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `#with` to set the data context then just use the keys directly:

```
<template name="hutch">
{{#with book}}
  Title: {{title}}
  Publisher: {{publisher}}
  etc...
{{/with}}
</template.
```

Then as @blueren suggests, use `.findOne()` to return a single book:

```
Template.hutch.helpers({
  'book'(){
    return BookList.findOne(randomBook);
  }
});
```

Comment: Fantastic, it was the {{with}} data context setting I needed. Such a simple solution, thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your random book document looks like :

```
{
  bookName: "TheRandomBook",
  bookAuthors: "RandomAuthor",
  bookPublishedYear: 1969,
  ....

}
```

**helper.js:**

Since you want only one book, use findOne instead of find since `findOne` will return you exactly one object, whereas `find` will return a cursor to iterate over the objects.

```
getRandomBook: function(){
   return books.findOne();
}
```

**showBooks.html:**

```
<htmlTag> {{getRandomBook.bookName}} </htmlTag>
<htmlTag> {{getRandomBook.bookAuthor}} </htmlTag>
<htmlTag> {{getRandomBook.bookbookPublishedYear}} </htmlTag>
```

Comment: But  see if the function getRandomBook does indeed return a random book, each time it is called from the HTML by way of {{getRandomBook.Value}}, the values won't line up. So you might get. Title: Moby Dick. Author: J.K. Rowling. PublishedYear: 2016

Comment: This does not make sense. If the object contains ```{Title: moby Dick, author: JK Rowling, PublishedYear: 2016}``` then that is what it will show. There is no way it is going to pick Title from a particular object, Author form a completely different object all together. UNLESS, you're calling the ```findOne``` helper for each of those. Can you also put an understanable snippet of your html code?

Comment: `<tr>
       <td><strong>Title:</strong></td>
       <td class="titleField">{{getRandomBook.Title}}</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><strong>Year:</strong></td>
       <td class="yearField">{{getRandomBook.Year}}</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><strong>Rating:</strong></td>
       <td class="ratingField">{{getRandomBook.Rating}}</td>`

Comment: The issue is in the getRandomBook function. It doesn't return the same book every time, so when it is called in each different part of the HTML, it selects a different book.